# Detail Formatter: code snippet cannot refer to other classes whose import is not declared

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse Oxygen.3a

I have a class which is a representation of an XML file. This class does not have `toString()` overridden. I want to use `Detail Formatter` to show the pretty-print format of the XML it is representing.

**Detail Formatter code snippet:**

```
try{
        String xml = getXmlString(); // This method returns single line string representation of the XML
        final InputSource src = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
        final Node document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(src).getDocumentElement();
        final Boolean keepDeclaration = Boolean.valueOf(xml.startsWith("<?xml"));
        final DOMImplementationRegistry registry = DOMImplementationRegistry.newInstance();
        final DOMImplementationLS impl = (DOMImplementationLS) registry.getDOMImplementation("LS");
        final LSSerializer writer = impl.createLSSerializer();

        writer.getDomConfig().setParameter("format-pretty-print", Boolean.TRUE); // Set this to true if the output needs to be beautified.
        writer.getDomConfig().setParameter("xml-declaration", keepDeclaration); // Set this to true if the declaration is needed to be outputted.

        return writer.writeToString(document);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        return getXmlString();
    }
```

The problem is that, the class for which I am defining this does not have import declaration for many of the classes I am using in the code snippet. This results in below error:

```
Detail formatter error:
    InputSource cannot be resolved to a type
    InputSource cannot be resolved to a type
    StringReader cannot be resolved to a type
    Node cannot be resolved to a type
    DOMImplementationRegistry cannot be resolved to a type
    DOMImplementationRegistry cannot be resolved
    DOMImplementationLS cannot be resolved to a type
    DOMImplementationLS cannot be resolved to a type
    LSSerializer cannot be resolved to a type
```

How can this be achieved? If Detail Formatter cannot support this, is there any other way to achieve this?

*NOTE* *This class is a legacy class for which I am trying to write Detail Formatter. I have the source code but I cannot make any changes in this class.*

Comment: In eclipse: Ctrl+Shift+O will provide the imports.

Comment: @JoopEggen Ctrl+Shift+O will provide imports in the class itself. How to get the imports in the Detail Formatter's code snippet box?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/3556925/2670892

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use full class path.
For example:

```
java.lang.String xml = getXmlString();
```